# ошибка передачи вектора в функцию C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

При написании многопоточного приложения на c++ возникла необходимость передачи в функцию, которая выполняется в многопоточном режиме (multy), некоторое количество ссылок на вектора, которые для каждого потока имеют собственное значение. В результате компиляции вылетают ошибки:

1. Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
2. Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type
   std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept()'

Код консольного приложения ниже:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "libraries.h"
#include "globalVariables.h"
//#include "multyThreadingFunc.h"


thread_local double centerOfMass = 0.0;

thread_local double templateZ;


vector<float> distanceAxis(n_bin + 1);

//here the total number of molecules in each bin is saved during the loop for the analyte molecules
vector<double> vectordensity(n_bin);

mutex mtx;

void multy(FILE &fid, int &amountOfAtoms, float &time, vector<float> &coordinates, vector<float> &changedCoord, double &centerOfMass, double &templateZ, vector<double> &vectordensity) {

    FILE *file = &fid;
    ...//some calculating
}

int main()
{
    thread_local vector<float> coordinates(3); //x,y,z coordinates
    thread_local vector<double> changedCoord;

    FILE *fid = fopen("Benzene_Simu1_0_35ns.gro","rt"); 
    if (fid == NULL) throw exception("Error was happend with the file");

    float time;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n_bin; i++) {
        distanceAxis[i] = (i - 0.5)*BinWidth;
    }

    int startTime = clock();
    while (true) {
        std::thread thr(multy, ref(fid), &amountOfAtoms, &time, ref(coordinates), ref(changedCoord), &centerOfMass, &templateZ, ref(vectordensity));

        if (feof(fid)) break;

        vectordensity[bin]++;   //sorts the molecules according to their bins
                                //after finishing the loop, density contains the distribution of the molecules over all bins for all time steps

        index++;
    }
    --index;

    fclose(fid);
    cout << endl << (endTime - startTime) / 1000 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Насчёт ошибки с созданием std::thread не знаю, но Вы читаете из одного файла в разных потоках а потом проверяете в цикле `feof(fid)`. И в каждом потоке не проверяете `feof`, то есть когда очередной поток попытается прочитать из файла, в котором уже конец - вы получите ошибку. А ещё вы создадите очень много потоков если данных в файле достаточно много. Создавать потоков больше чем ядер в процессоре не целесообразно. Точнее - больше чем возвращает специальный метод `std::thread::hardware_concurrency();`

Comment: Извините, прислал не полный код. В потоке main, после создания потока планировалось написать цикл чтения определённого числа строк, которые обрабатываются в дочерних потоках. ТО есть это своего рода холостой ход в потоке main и полезная работа с пропущенными строками в параллельных потоках.

Comment: @DenisDanilov Вообще-то стоило бы радикально сократить код оставив только пару строк для воспроизведения указанной ошибки. Код в вопросах **должен быть минимальным** для демонстрации проблемы. Не стоит вываливать сюда все как есть.

Comment: Понял, учту на будущее. Спасибо за комментарии.

Comment: @DenisDanilov Лучше учесть на настоящее. Под вопросом же есть кнопка *Править*, позволяющая его редактировать.

Comment: Ок, часть лишнего кода вы убрали, но указанная проблема в оставшемся коде не воспроизводится. При компиляции будет *"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pch.h': No such file or directory"*.  Видимо вас вводит в заблуждение разное значение `&` в разных контекстах. При объявлении типа этот символ обозначает ссылку, а в других случаях (внезапно) - взятие адреса. Обычно для передачи по ссылке никаких действий не требуется, однако для передачи в `thread` надо использовать `std::ref` (иначе произойдет копирование по значению). `thread_local` используется неправильно, и нет `join` потока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написана какая-то ерунда при передаче аргументов в поток. Например, в функции потока параметр

```
int &amountOfAtoms
```

это ссылка на `int`, а при создании потока вы передаете туда

```
&amountOfAtoms
```

т.е. указатель на `int`. Эта ошибка присутствует и с другими параметрами. Неудивительно что компилятор не может вызвать функцию потока. Что характерно, ссылки на векторы вы передаете правильно, а ссылки на скалярные значения почему-то нет. Откуда такое деление?

С параметром `fid` вообще что-то непонятное творится. Почему передается `ref(fid)` (то есть фактически `FILE *&`), когда функция потока принимает `FILE &`? Что вообще такое `FILE &` и зачем вам понадобился этот `FILE &`? Почему вы не передаете сразу нормальный человеческий `FILE *`?

Также я у вас в коде не увидел никаких попыток сделать "некоторое количество ссылок на вектора, которые для каждого потока имеют собственное значение". Для того, чтобы у каждого потока было "собственное значение" вектора, надо для каждого потока создавать отдельный экземпляр вектора. Но я у вас этого нигде не вижу. Все потоки получают ссылки на одни и те же векторы. В частности, неясно, зачем вы у себя в коде наставили этих `thread_local` спецификаторов, если все потоки получают ссылки на одни и те же данные из главного потока и работают именно с ними.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии по коду, я несколько наобум пытался исправить возникавшие комментарии от среды. То есть по вашему мнению проблемы с invoke - это следствие неправильной передачи параметров?

Comment: @Denis Danilov: Проблемы с invoke - именно от несовпадения типов параметров.

Comment: Смотрите, насколько я понял, я неправильно передаю скалярные аргументы в функцию потока? То есть при создании потока я пишу &time, а принимаю в функции как int &time

Comment: @DenisDanilov Да, именно так. В том числе этот `fid`.

Comment: Это неверно, как Я понял. А как правильно? Просто немного путаюсь с указателями и ссылками.

Comment: @DenisDanilov: Если вы хотите принимать переменную как `int &time`, то передавать ее надо как `std::ref(time)`, т.е. точно так же, как вы передаете векторы. Если вы хотите принимать переменную как `int *time`, то передавать ее надо как `&time`. Если вы хотите принимать переменную как `int time`, то передавать ее надо как просто `time`.